# UITabbar disappears when i push view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This is my app delegate:

```
    // Initialize your five tab controllers.  with each tab has its own navigation controller
    HomePageView *homePageView = [[HomePageView alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homePageView];
    [nav1.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    // Set nav Bar to be completely transparent
    [nav1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nav1.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    nav1.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    //Set Title
    nav1.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";

    ProfileViewController *profileViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];

    // Set Title
    nav2.tabBarItem.title = @"Profile";

    // Set nav Bar to be completely transparent
    [nav2.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nav2.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    nav2.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    FeedViewController *feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:feedViewController];

    // Set nav Bar to be completely transparent
    [nav3.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nav3.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    nav3.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    // Set Title
    nav3.tabBarItem.title = @"Feeds";

    ListeningSessionViewController *listeningSessionViewController= [[ListeningSessionViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listeningSessionViewController];

    // Set nav Bar to be completely transparent
    [nav4.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nav4.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    nav4.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    // set Title
    nav4.tabBarItem.title = @"Mussion";

    RecievedViewController *recievedViewController =[[RecievedViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recievedViewController];

    // Set nav Bar to be completely transparent
    [nav5.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nav5.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    nav5.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    // Set Title
    nav5.tabBarItem.title = @"Recieved";

    // Set selected tab bar background
    UIImage *whiteBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBackground"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:whiteBackground];

    self.tabC.tabBar.translucent = YES;

    // initialize tabbarcontroller,set your viewcontrollers and change its color.
    self.tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5, nil];
    [self.tabC setViewControllers: controllers animated:NO];

    //[_window addSubview:self.tabC.view];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabC];

    // Show window
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

When i push a view controller from one of the tabbar controllers eg HomePageView, The tabbar disappears:

```
SearchSongViewController *Search_MusicTableView = [[SearchSongViewController alloc] init];
    Search_MusicTableView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:Search_MusicTableView animated:YES];
```

When i present the modal view or even push another view controller, the tabbar disappears, please why is this ? and how do i fix it, Thanks alot !

Comment: Well, the code you're showing is a presentation not a push, which should hide the tab bar. Have you actually tried a push, and that hid the tab bar? BTW, presentModalViewController:animated: has been depreciated for a long time now, so you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Thanks alot ! lool that was pretty dumb of me :D

Comment: @rdelmar - you can post your comment as an answer. and then Pizzy213codes - you can accept that answer and close the question.